# How to add coordinates in MKMapView from NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I have a table view with about 5 rows in it, one array that stores the latitude and another that stores longitude
Now if i select 2nd row, the 2 object from both the arrays should be called and displayed on the map.
Is there a way to do this?
or will i have to manually enter coordinates without array?

Answer (score 1):

Implement the UITableViewDelegate's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and when it is called, grab the latitude and longitude from the arrays and add an annotation to your map.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat latitude = latitudes[indexPath.row];
    CGFloat longitude = longitudes[indexPath.row];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = coordinate;
    point.title = @"Title";

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
}
```